# Akka to Scala Cats FS2 migration

Tags: scala, akka-stream, scala-cats, cats-effect, fs2

"Source" and "OverflowStrategy" are parts of Akka streams. How can I reimplement below code in FS2?

```
object Topic {
  def apply: Topic = {
    val (a1, a2) = Source.queue[Message[_]](100, OverflowStrategy.backpressure).preMaterialize()
    val (b1, b2) = Source.queue[Signal](100, OverflowStrategy.backpressure).preMaterialize()
    new Topic(a1, a2, b1, b2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

In fs2 there are several constructors, for example `Queue.bounded[F, M](maxSize)` or `Queue.circularBuffer[F, M](maxSize)`. For backpressure you should use `Queue.bounded[F, M](maxSize)`. It will do the same as the backpressure strategy for akka queue.

The full list of methods:
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/co.fs2/fs2-core_2.13/2.2.2/fs2/concurrent/Queue$.html

You will have something like this:

```scala
object Topic {
  def apply[F]: F[Topic] = for {
    a <- Queue.bounded[F, Message[_]](100)
    b <- Queue.bounded[F, Signal](100)
  } yield new Topic(a, b)
}
```

Also, you can consider using prebuild Topic type from FS2. https://www.javadoc.io/doc/co.fs2/fs2-core_2.13/2.2.2/fs2/concurrent/Topic.html

> Topic allows you to distribute A published by arbitrary number of publishers to arbitrary number of subscribers.
> Topic has built-in back-pressure support implemented as maximum bound (maxQueued) that a subscriber is allowed to enqueue. Once that bound is hit, publishing may semantically block until the lagging subscriber consumes some of its queued elements.